# In psycopg2, how do I use register_hstore with connection pools?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use psycopg2 in many python projects, and frequently use HSTORE as a postgres data type.

Typically I create my connections as follows:

```
connection =psycopg2.connect(...) 
psycopg2.extras.register_hstore(connection)
```

which then allows seamless integration between Python `dicts` and Postgres `hstores`.

However, if I want to use connection pools, apparently I have to write:

```
pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(...)
```

and then use it with

```
connectionFromPool = pool.getconn()
```

But if run `register_hstore(connectionFromPool)`  every time I ask for it, then the function will get called multiple times on the same connection. Will this cause side-effects?  Isn't the whole point of connection pooling to avoid unnecessary calls?

Is there some way of telling `SimpleConnectionPool` to use `register_hstore` when it creates the connection initially?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `psycopg2.extras.register_hstore(connection, globally=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I wrote a subclass to override the `_connect` method:

```
class MyConnectionPool(BasePoolClass):
    getconn = BasePoolClass._getconn
    putconn = BasePoolClass._putconn
    closeall   = BasePoolClass._closeall

    def _connect(self, key=None):
        conn= BasePoolClass._connect(self, key)
        psycopg2.extras.register_hstore(conn,unicode=True)
        psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE,conn)
        return conn
```

Which can then be used in place of `SimpleConnectionPool`